# Unity3d UI events not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, unity3d-gui

I'm developing iOS & Android game using Unity 4.6.4. My UI stuff works well on Android devices. However, on iOS devices UI appearance is OK but they're not working properly. Button onClick events are not working, button animations work though - that is why I guess it is something about event system of the UI.

**Here is my log in Xcode:**

```
NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.

at System.Type.GetGenericArguments () [0x00000] in :0

at System.Type.MakeGenericType (System.Type[] typeArguments) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCall.GetObjectCall (UnityEngine.Object target, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, UnityEngine.Events.ArgumentCache arguments) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCall.GetRuntimeCall (UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase theEvent) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCallGroup.Initialize (UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList invokableList, UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase unityEventBase) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.RebuildPersistentCallsIfNeeded () [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in :0

at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) [0x00000] in :0
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Show the code that causes that error.

Comment: It is not something that i can show because it is very common in my project (as i said it is UI stuff and there are a lot of UI stuff in the project). Crucial point is code is OK(also they're simple stuffs, generally adding OnClick methods of Buttons on Inspector), its being working properly on Android is an indicator of that. As i understand iOS part requires some kind of Settings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the 'Stripping Level' selection in PlayerSettings, you'd best choose 'Disabled'.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a disabled option, at least in 2020.1